# Flattening a PDF file completely using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I'm merging PDF documents using iTextsharp. Every now and then it removes a layer, and sometimes the layers stay.

Here's the code and an example is added as well, it is flattening as it's supposed to on most occasions.

Its just a few times when a file comes from several people it removes the layers during the merge process.

```
  private byte[] FlattenPdfFormToBytes(PdfReader reader)
  {
       var memStream = new MemoryStream();
       var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memStream) 
       { 
             FormFlattening = true,
             FreeTextFlattening = true,
             AnnotationFlattening =true
       };
   }
```

[image: Layers Removed]

Comment: Are you saying that some of your PDFs are *"protected"* simply by adding a black rectangle on top of a scan? Do you know that you could get fired for such practices? See [Readers 'declassify' US document](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/europe/4506517.stm) and [AT&T leaks sensitive info in NSA suit](http://archive.is/cwOg). I could help you, but as long as you don't use proper redaction, that would make me an accomplice to a bad practice and I don't want that.

Comment: Just flattening the black rectangle won't remove the sensitive data! You need to use redaction to remove all traces that allow people to read what's under the black rectangle. In your case, it's sufficient to extract the scanned image from the PDF to find out what's hidden.

Comment: That is the problem others upload these PDF and we can't know what they are uploading. This is the reason I'm asking for help. It's not my org uploading the files. It's others.

Comment: Hello Bruno,How do I  "extract the scanned image from the PDF to find out what's hidden" Thanks.

Comment: In Adobe Reader, just select the image and use "Save as". Programmatically, e.g. using iText's image extraction example. In any case: the people who upload the "anonimized" PDFs need to be warned that their PDFs aren't anonymous!